# Python - populate a list containing variables from another module

Tags: python, list

Is there a way in Python that you can compile variables from a module into a list with out manually doing it?

For example:

```
#catName.py
cat1 = "toby"
cat2 = "bill"
cat3 = "sally"
catList = [cat1,cat2,cat3]

#printCatNames.py
import catName
for names in catName.catList:
    print names
```

What I am trying to do (using the example above) is auto populate `catList` when the module `catName` is called. If someone could point me in the right direction, it would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Your code works perfectly as-is. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: try this: import catName and then dir(catName)

Comment: `catList = [val for name, val in globals().items() if not name.startswith('__')]` This will auto-update `catList` from within catName.py. Just make sure it executes after all the variables have been named.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is along the lines that I am looking for!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import  catName

n [3]: [v for k,v in catName.__dict__.items() if not k.startswith("__")]
Out[3]: ['toby', 'sally', 'bill']
```

I would personally stick to manually filling the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The actual task is to use directory file names instead of cat names. Due to there being a large number of variables containing directory file names, I was looking a some to to populate the list automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat1 = "toby"
cat2 = "bill"
cat3 = "sally"
catList = [v for k, v in vars().items() if k.startswith('cat')]
```

It's usually preferable to just write the list explicitly however

```
catList = ["toby", "bill", "sally"]
```

or, for longer lists

```
catList = [
    "toby",
    "bill",
    "sally",
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, but I think your answer might be:

```
>>> from catName import catList
```

this will allow you to:

```
>>> print(catList)
['toby', 'bill', 'sally']
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. What I wanted to do was to auto populate a list containing the variable for the cat names within the module catName and then import that list into printCat.py